# Creating a Choice Type field dynamically on Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

Im quite new with Symfony and i'm looking for a way to dynamically create a choicetype field in a form.

In fact i have several product that i fetch with the query_builder in my form.
After presenting the product and the price, i want a select dropdown so the user can select the quantity of products to get.

In fact, in my builder form, i fetch the products thanks to the query builder, and get +/- 30 products, but this number can change.

The problem is that i want as many dropdowns as products, until now my builder looks like this :

```
        return $builder
        ->add('price', EntityType::class ,[
            'class'=> Price::class,
            'query_builder' => function (PriceRepository $pr) use ($goldenOptions, $currentCompany){
                return $pr->getPrice($goldenOptions, $currentCompany->getOrder()->getCompanyType(),  $currentCompany->getOnboardingRevenues(), true);
            },
            'expanded'=>true,
            'multiple'=>true,
            'placeholder'=>true 
        ])
        ->add('quantity',ChoiceType::class,[
            'choices'=>['mensuel'=>true,'trimestriel'=>false,'1'=>1,'2'=>2,'3'=>3,'4'=>4],
            'expanded'=>false,
            'multiple'=>false
        ])
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class,[
            'attr' => ['class' => 'save'],
            'label'=>'Sauvegarder',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-purple btn-rounded']
        ])
```

problem is that this way i only get 1 dropdown, and i want several. I have managed to reproduced it with javascript but when  i handle the request and getData from it, Symfony only recognise the first 'quantity' field.

If anyone as ideas on how can i created myultiples 'quantity' fields and symfony recognized them thanks. Maybe an event listener but i have no clue how i could actually do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is for some kind of e-commerce app where you have a cart with products and want to select quantity.

I would have an entity for "Cart", that holds many "CartProduct" that each have one "Product" as a relationship and other attributes for quantity etc.

With this you can have a CartForm that embeds any number of CartProductForm with quantity etc. for each one.

Same as the example in the docs, where "Task" would be "Cart" and "Tags" would be "CartProducts":
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html